# Why is state not updating

Tags: reactjs

State (enable_button) is not updating in this:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        user_id: '',
        password: '',
        error: null,
        enable_button: true
    };
},

loginStart: function() {
    this.setState({enable_button: false});
    console.log("loginStart", this.state);
},

loginEnd: function() {
    this.setState({enable_button: true});
    console.log("loginEnd", this.state);
},

componentWillMount: function () {
    UserStore.on("login_start", this.loginStart);
    UserStore.on("login_end", this.loginEnd);
},

componentWillUnmount: function () {
    UserStore.removeListener("login_start", this.loginStart);
    UserStore.removeListener("login_end", this.loginEnd);
},
```

In my render function I have this:

```
<div className="col-sm-12 controls">
    <button type="submit" href="#"
            className="btn btn-primary pull-right"
            disabled={!this.state.enable_button}>
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> </span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Log in
    </button>
</div>
```

I see that the functions do fire, but enable_button always stays true.

Comment: Is `enable_button` always true in your render function as well? I ask because `setState` does not immediately update state so your console.log will always report the previous value when called immediately after `setState`

Comment: Yes, that is the first thing I noticed and then began investigating what was up. I then saw that the value always remains true. I tried with a callback to be sure and even then it stayed true.

Comment: Is anything else mutating the state? Is it possible `loginEnd` is being called as well before the component is rendered thus reseting `enable_button` to true?

Comment: Are you sure react _updates_ the component and does not re-render the entire component (triggering another `getInitialState`)? I ask because the button is of type `Submit`, which tends to cause a reload (unless you `event.preventDefault()`)

Comment: I have a e.preventDefault() in place @wittvelt

Comment: @ryanjduffy I will try to do a console.log in the render and see the order of exection maybe.

Comment: @DennisDecoene is the event listener invoked at all? how are you invoking them?

Comment: I can see that the event listeners are fired in the console.log prints

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. It was nothing to do with react in itself.

I was doing an ajax call in the userActions, there the two events fired of simultaneously instead of sequentially and therefore I got this strange behaviour.